# Simple HTML CSS responsiveness without media query

Tags: html, css

I created this code pen here:

https://codepen.io/Zenpi/pen/abWgLzy

```
    .div1 {
      display:inline-block;
      min-width:33%;
      max-width:100%;
      width:calc((480px — 100%) * 480);
      background-color: blue;
      height: 100px;
    }
    .div2 {
      display:inline-block;
      min-width:33%;
      max-width:100%;
      width:calc((480px — 100%) * 480);
      background-color: green;
      height: 100px;
    }
    .div3 {
      display:inline-block;
      min-width:33%;
      max-width:100%;
      width:calc((480px — 100%) * 480);
      background-color: orange;
      height: 100px;
    }
```

Following these two rules of css:

1. If the width value is greater than the max-width value, max-width wins.
2. If the min-width value is greater than the width or max-width values, min-width wins.

According to these rules, we should see, that the boxes are in a row, when the window width is greater than 480px. On my machine, it's always in a column. Can someone explain this to me?
Thank you very much.

Edit:
Thank you for reminding me @Heretic Monkey. Here is also the html

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
```

Also this was solved by @Temani Afif. This was a weird type issue, because the minus, was not really a minus sign. Thanks so much!

Comment: Please follow the advice in [ask], where it says, "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself.** Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."

Comment: typo issue, you are using a strange minus sign, use `-` instead of `—`

Comment: Thats it!!! How did you figure that out. Thank you so much. I thought I was going crazy. How can I mark this as solved by you @TemaniAfif ?

Comment: well, after doing CSS all this time I can notice if the minus sign is having some extra pixels ;) [no need to mark anything, this question fall into the off-topic category since it's a typo issue]

Comment: Issues like this can often be caught by using a good editor and/or a linting package that will warn you about unexpected CSS properties/values/syntax, it might be worth looking into one, they save us all headaches every now and then.